# Mapping the alphabet to certain values in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, mapping

I am working on a function stdord(ch).  According to my assignment, when any positive integer 0-9 is entered, it will return 0-9.  However, letters are different.  If the user enters 'A' it'll be '10', 'a' 11, 'B' 12, 'b' 13.... all the way down to 'Z' 60 and 'z' 61.  Now, the assignment says to map it and he recommends mapping the capital letters 'A'-'Z' to 0-25, then multiplying it by 2 and adding 10 and doing similar things for the lower case.  I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I can solve the problem by simply creating a list containing 0-9 and 'A', 'a' to 'Z', 'z', but this doesn't solve the problem the way my professor specifies.  I don't really understand dictionaries too well.  I would like to turn it in for a good grade rather than this subpar solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Can't use functions like numpy, zip, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this to get started:

```
letterMap = {}
lowers = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
for x in lowers :
    letterMap[x]=(2*lowers.index(x)+1)+10

uppers = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
for x in uppers :
    letterMap[x]=(2*uppers.index(x))+10

print (letterMap)
```

Comment: Says "global name 'string' is not defined".  I am assuming that string is supposed to be something I import.  If this is the case, I'm not allowed to use it :(

Comment: You need to import string.

Comment: I'm not allowed to import string.

Comment: Replace the list( string.ascii_lowercase ) with 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Comment: Thanks for the help! I altered it and this is what it comes up with.  Now I just need to put in a bit so that when the user enters in 0-9 it gives 0-9.  Could you explain to me how the .index feature works? I know, I should know.
letterMap = {}
    lowers = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    for x in lowers:
        letterMap[x]=(2*lowers.index(x)+1)+10
        
    uppers = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    for x in uppers:
        letterMap[x]=(2*uppers.index(x))+10
        
    print (letterMap[ch])